# Generalization of the Saccheri-Legendre Theorem Proof

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

So I'm working on generalizing the Saccheri-Legendre Theorem to convex $n$-gons.

[$\underline{\text{Saccheri-Legendre Theorem:}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccheri%E2%80%93Legendre_theorem) The sum of the angles of a triangle is at most $180^\circ$.

A triangle is an $n$-gon where $n=3$. So to generalize I would want a formula for any $n$. Which follows, I believe, the same formula as the formula in Euclidean geometry for angle measure of a triangle. So I could say the following.

$\underline{\text{Generalization of the Sacceri-Legendre Theorem:}}$ For any $n$-gon the angle measure of that $n$-gon is at most $2\cdot(n-2)\cdot90^\circ$.

So for my proof I'm assuming that I'm going to have to show that any $n$-gon can break up into $m$ different triangles. Then I can say by the Saccheri-Legendre Theorem that all of the $m$ different triangles add up to $180^\circ$. That way it would just be $m$ different Saccheri-Legendre proofs which I can easily prove since we've used it before.

Just want to make sure that I am on the right track and not looking at this completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. Every convex $n$-gon can be divided into $n-2$ triangles. So the sum $S$ of the internal angles of the $n$-gon is $(n-2)S_\triangle \leq (n-2)180^\circ$, where $S_\triangle$ is the sum of the internal angles of the triangle (if you want to apply Saccheri-Legendre for triangles right of the bat).

Comment: I just didn't know if saying that all convex $n$-gons can be divided into $n-2$ triangles is something that I have to prove or if I can just say it's true and move on. Then once I have it broken up into $m$ different triangles and apply the Saccheri Legendre Theorem is that enough?

Comment: @Fmonkey2001: For completeness, you should prove that a convex $n$-gon can be divided into $n-2$ triangles. It's not difficult. Just show that convexity allows you to cut off a corner at a time, breaking the $n$-gon into a triangle and a convex $(n-1)$-gon. Induction kicks in from there.

Comment: Sorry, I went out to eat a bit. Blue's answer is what I would have said, go for it!